# Поиск в базе по ключу

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, поиск, linq2sql

Вот какая штука.

Дан ключ, база данных MS SQL, LINQ и c#:)
Нужно выбрать из базы только те записи, которые в определённом поле содержат (в качестве подстроки) этот ключ.

Хотелось бы узнать наиболее эффективные методы поиска. Всмысле, например такое:

```
_dataContext.User.Select(p => p.Name.Contains(key))
```

Здесь каждую запись проверяем, выполняя метод Contains, который, я так понимаю, работает за линейное время.

Я понимаю, что можно как-нибудь захэшить поля Name и возиться с такой ерундой...

Может есть другие варианты, по-проще в реализации или уже реализованные?

Comment: "Уже реализованные" это типа "бери и используй", не выдумывая сам алгоритм поиска:)

Comment: Захэшить - это я так понимаю - снять хэш с поля и его использовать для поиска. А чтобы найти по подстроке - это надо снять хэши со всех подстрок в полях. Что-то сомневаюсь.

Comment: Ну захэшить все подстроки нужно только после добавления записи в базу. Храним эти коды в массиве (лучше отсортированном, чтобы использовать бинпоиск). А потом уже, при запросе на поиск, искать по этим кодам.

Comment: И на какой выигрыш рассчитан такой громоздкий механизм?

Comment: А как вы думаете, зачем я задал вопрос?

Comment: Для поиска строк в базе есть [полнотекстовый поиск](http://www.google.ru/search?aq=0&oq=MSSQL+%D0%9F%D0%9E%D0%9B%D0%9D%D0%9E&sourceid=chrome&client=ubuntu&channel=cs&ie=UTF-8&q=mssql+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA), его и используйте.

Comment: А если информация, которую необходимо найти мультиязыковая?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LINQ2SQL не будет вытаскивать все данные из БД. Он сформирует к БД запрос вида

```
SELECT * FROM USER WHERE NAME LIKE '%key%'
```

и при переборе элементов, возвращённых запросом, объекты будут формироваться только для найденных данных.

Для того чтобы посмотреть, что за запросы к БД генерирует Linq2Sql, у контекста есть свойство Log. Изменяя значение этого свойства, можно перенаправить логгирование запросов куда угодно. Например, можно использовать командную строку (System.Console.Out).

Comment: А если у меня, например, 10млн записей, насколько эффективным будет этот "перебор элементов"?

Comment: Для реализации полнотекстового поиска в очень больших таблицах обычно рекомендуется связывать их со словарём слов, по которым осуществляется поиск. При сохранении полная строка сохраняется в свою колонку, плюс она разбивается на слова, которые дополняют словарь, и формируются связи созданной записи со словарём. При извлечении данных вместо оператора LIKE используется вложенный запрос к словарю.

Comment: Полнотекстовый поиск работает только с каким-то определённым языком... или нет? Моя информация может содержать символы из различных языков

Comment: Можно с любым. Вдумайтесь в алгоритм, который я написал